# how to solve eulers integration for set of equation with matlab

Tags: matlab

[**the sets of equations**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9tUP.png)

I have tried basically using ode45 but receiving an error:

```
Warning: Failure at t=1.570741e+00. Unable to meet integration tolerances
without reducing the step size below the smallest value allowed (3.552714e-15)
at time t.
```

The  initial conditions for eulers integration areas follows:
`h = 0.25, t = 0, x[0] = 0 , x[1] = 2, x[2] = 10`

My code is

tuto.m

```
function dx=tuto(t,x)

dx1=x(1)^2+1;

dx2=t*sin(x(1)+x(2));

dx3=sin(cos(x(1))+sin(x(3)));

dx=[dx1;dx2;dx3];
```

main.m

```
% To solve the system of equations dx1/dt=x2; dx2/dt=-x11
% It uses the file tuto.m

clear all % Clear all

t=[0 30]; % Time span

xinit=[0;2;10]; % Initial condition

[t,x]=ode45(@tuto,t,xinit); % Integrate equations

%plot(t,x(:,1)) % Plot x1 vs t

%title('CFB'); xlabel('t'); ylabel('x1');

%plot(t,x(:,2)) % Plot x2 vs t

%title('CFB'); xlabel('t'); ylabel('x2');

%plot(t,x(:,3)) %plot x3 vs t

plot3(x(:,1),x(:,2),x(:,3)) % Plot x2 vs x1

%title('CFB'); xlabel('x1'); ylabel('x2)');
```

Comment: i apologise the equations are in the blue link.

Comment: Please edit your original question to provide the full code you're using so that we can try to replicate your issue. Don't use the comments to provide code.

Comment: updated my code. please see the full code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I include h=0.25 in t like t=[0:0.25:30]; the error goes away running the main script.I can get the proper graphs too.